# AWS PHP SDK: Bucket Encryption Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a script to create a Bucket using PHP AWS SDK Ver 3.

```
 try {
        // bucket creation
        $this->s3->createBucket([
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
        ]);

        // set the encryption type
        $result = $this->s3->putBucketEncryption([
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration' => [
                'Rules' => [
                    'ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault' => [
                        'KMSMasterKeyID' => $key,
                        'SSEAlgorithm' => 'aws:kms'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
        return true;
    } catch(S3Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
```

The bucket is created, however the encryption is not working and is set to NONE when I checked the console. When I log the results, I can only see an empty body and no errors at all. The key ID i'm passing is the Key Id from the  customer managed keys not the ARN.

Again to test this, I tried using the default server side encryption by updating my  ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault to use the SSEAlgorithm to AES256 however checking this in the AWS console no encryption is still logged on the bucket.

[image: AWS CONSOLE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot add parameters like array in key `Rules`

```
result = $this->s3->putBucketEncryption([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration' => [
        'Rules' => [
            [ // forget add array
                'ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault' => [
                    'KMSMasterKeyID' => $key,
                    'SSEAlgorithm' => 'aws:kms', // REQUIRED
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Hope it's help you. Check please the [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putbucketencryption).